# How to make a rest API in Exchange with a specific API instance visible for everyone? so they can call it from postman or other tools

Tags: api, rest, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I created an API with different endpoints in design center, and published it to exchange.

I'm using a specific API instance different than the mock to run this API and get real data instead of mock example.

How can I make this visible for everyone so they can test it as well?

Comment: if you have implemented your API then i believe you need to deploy the mule application on cloudhub so that it can be accessed to cater the real data to the accessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to share the API to Public Portal using share option in exchange view. Once you do this anyone can view your API in exchange by hitting https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/Domain_Name/ where Domain_Name is your domain. You can follow the steps provided in below link.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/to-share-api-asset-to-portal